# APi platform autoloader issue in Symfony app

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a fresh installation of symfony with usage of https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker and additionally I added api platfomr by running `composer require api` and afterwards I able to open api documentaion in broswer but I can't run any CLI command and getting error

```
  The autoloader expected class "ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Command\OpenApiCommand" to be defined in file "/srv/app/vendor/composer/../api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Command/OpenApiCommand.php". The file was found but the class was not in  
   it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I'm a bit confused as I literally did nothing except of havig fresh symfony installation and additional Api platform dependency

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105479/openapicommand-is-not-defined

Comment: please create it as an answer, will accept it, thank you!

Comment: BTW after downgradeing to 3.1.8 now I have error ` Attempted to load interface "ResourceClassResolverInterface" from namespace "ApiPlatform\Api". Did you forget a "use" statement for "ApiPlatform\Metadata\ResourceClassResolverInterface"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed. Update api platform bundle: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5575

Answer (score -1):

I've exactly the same problem since this morning. Never noticed any problem before today. MAybe its related to the last Symfony 6.2 version or the last "api" packages installed via "composer require api".