# OpenAPICommand is not defined

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am new to Symfony, I was simply following an api setup tutorial when I tried the following command: `php bin/console make:factory`, and got the following error:

```
 In DebugClassLoader.php line 350:
The autoloader expected class "ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Command\OpenApiCommand" to be defined in file "/Users/myUsername/Sites/localhost/myProject/vendor/composer/../api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Bundle/Command/OpenApiCommand.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

I looked at the class, which has the following contents; I don't understand how it could be defined considering the code:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Command;

class_exists(\ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Command\OpenApiCommand::class);

if (false) {
    final class OpenApiCommand extends \ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Command\OpenApiCommand
    {
    }
}
```

The class definition is in a clause that is statically false.
All code in the project so far is generated; I did not change any files. Does anyone know how or why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

It seems, there is a bug on version 3.1.9 of api-platform : https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5567

You can rollback to previous version with following command or wait for the bugfix

```bash
composer require api-platform/core:3.1.7
```

This will fixe the version of api-platform to 3.1.8. After the bugfix, you will need to restore your old version regex :

```bash
composer require api-platform/core:^3.1
```

Edit : rollback to 3.1.7 because of issue https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5558

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing the PR linked to the issue locally for now and it works.

Comment: after downgradeing to 3.1.8 now I have error `  Attempted to load interface "ResourceClassResolverInterface" from namespace "ApiPlatform\Api".  
  Did you forget a "use" statement for "ApiPlatform\Metadata\ResourceClassResolverInterface"?   `

Comment: @BogdanDubyk There is an other issuer on 3.1.8 : https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5558 about ApiPlatform\Api\ResourceClassResolverInterface

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to install foundry before executing the command. Everything is working as expected now. I think it was a bizarre error to get for a missing dependency. If anyone has input to explain this for me to get a better understanding it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Having the same issue since today. How exactly did you solve it? I tried adding:
"zenstruck/browser": "^1.4",
"zenstruck/foundry": "^1.31"

Still the same

Comment: I simply forgot to run `composer require foundry orm-fixtures --dev`

Answer (score 0):

update to higher version, problem disappears , I use 3.1.11